# Bootstrap bundle present in page source but not working

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm facing a very peculiar issue where the bootstrap css is working fine but the js is not working. The js shows in the page source. I am using cdn but I have also tried by downloading the bundle and enqueueing it.

I've tried the following two approaches and neither of them work.

Downloading bootstrap and enqueueing :

```
function test()
{
wp_enqueue_script('test', get_theme_file_uri('/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.js'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test');
```

Connecting it via CDN:

```
function ftw_files()
{

wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');

wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-bundle','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ftw_files');
```

The confusing part is that if I write some js in the bootstrap js file below or above the main line of code. For example:

```
alert("hello")
```

This works!!! How??? Is it because this is simpler?

I even added the full script tag directly in the footer.php inside the footer tags like this;

```
<script src ="..."></script>
```

but that doesn't work either.

I'll say it again, I can see several functional script tags pointing to bootstrap in the page source. For some reason, it doesn't work in the frontend. Is there a possibility for this to be a hosting issue because I've had two other major issues from this host. This same method works fine in localhost.

Image of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: If the JavaScript file is visible in the source then WordPress has done it's job. Whether and how the script works after that is purely a JavaScript issue unrelated to WordPress. You've proven that by showing that `alert()` works inside the file. That being said you haven't actually said what's not working. What are you expecting to happen that hasn't happened? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, the bootstrap styles are not showing. The bundle that I'm using in localhost is working fine. For eg: I can see the dark background when I give the class "bg-dark". I'm starting to think more and more that this is a host issue but I don't even know how the alert("hello") can work but not the actual bootstrap code.

Comment: I've added an image of what I mean.

Comment: Is the JS or the CSS the problem? Your question says “the bootstrap css is working” and asks about the script but now you’re saying the styles are the problem?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, the js bundle file will give you both styles and the js functions. If I just use a bootstrap css file which they have in their site, the styles load fine. But, if I use the js bundle file which gives me the style as well as the scripts, neither of them work becuase it is a .js file. It is a very weird issue.

Comment: What makes you think the bundle JS includes styles? When you download Bootstrap it comes with separate CSS and JS files: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/

Comment: Oh, you're right. Apparently, only the cdn has both combined. But, it still hasn't solved the issue because at this point, I have enqueued the styles and scripts in 3 different ways. The scripts just doesn't load. And, if I were to remove all the code and just use the bundled cdn, there is no style or script.

Comment: Even if the file is all js, the code above the alert should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't? What isn't working? You haven't explained.

Comment: The CDN *does not* serve any combined CSS + JS, nor any JS which automatically loads the CSS, nor any JS which programmatically adds CSS rules to the document. `bundle` just means that it's the output of a bundling tool - *not* that it's JS and CSS combined. The two are separate files in all instances, and must be enqueued as such. You say "the script just doesn't load" - but you've said the script/tags are printing to the markup and that a manually inserted `alert()` will trigger, which means they are loading, and are pointing to the correct files.